# Having dotnet core 2.0.0 Socket.Listen() support UNIX Domain Socket?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, unix-socket

According to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10981, I copied the implementation from corefx/src/System.Net.Sockets/tests/FunctionalTests/UnixDomainSocketTest.cs  and use it locally like below. (I'm using dotnet core 2.0.0 on Ubuntu)

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
Console.WriteLine(s.SendBufferSize);
Console.WriteLine(s.ReceiveBufferSize);

var unixSocket = "./my.sock.1";
var ep = new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(unixSocket);
Console.WriteLine(ep.AddressFamily);

try
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(unixSocket);
    s.Bind(ep);

    s.Listen(5);  // **Operation not supported**

    while(true)
    {
        var newS = s.Accept();

        byte[] content = new byte[1000];
        var result = s.Receive(content);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(content));
        newS.Close();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    s.Close();
}
```

The exception is something like below:

```
Operation not supported
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Listen(Int32 backlog)
   at test01.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/nonstatic/code/temp/test01/Program.cs:line 106
```

Is there any solution or workaround to let dotnet core build a domain socket server in Linux? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like @stephentoub replied with the answer on your [corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25088#issuecomment-342377827).

> Did you try SocketType.Stream instead of SocketType.Dgram?